# Python - spawn child process window if closed

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

Situation: I want a Python console window to be kept opened. The easiest way (or only way) I can think of is to have a parent process that spawns a daemon thread/process that spawns the CLI window, and if it ever `.join()`s, simply spawn it again.

```py
import threading

def prompt():
    while True:
        userDecision = input("Enter option: ")
        if userDecision == X:
            doSomething()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        prompt_t = threading.Thread(target=prompt)
        prompt_thread.start()
        prompt_thread.join()
        doStuffWhenThreadEnds()

#Something tells me that I should be spawning
#a shell instead of calling a function.
```

Problem: I am not very familiar with these modules.

Question: How would I go about using a parent process that will only react if the child process/thread `.join()`s and re-spawns the child process.

Comment: What about an infinite loop? `while True: thread = Thread(...); thread.start(); thread.join()` When the thread exits, it goes back and spawn a thread again.

Comment: @PanwenWang the only way my child thread exits is when the command line is closed or `Ctrl + C` is issued. and it causes a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception instead of letting it `.join()`.

Comment: Are you able to share your code?

Comment: @PanwenWang updated my question

Comment: You are in an infinite loop in your thread. When you get the userDecision, you should break the loop.

Comment: I see... I guess I would want your opinion as well -- will it be better to spawn a shell somehow, leave it this way, or is it personal prerference?

Comment: What do you mean by spawn a shell? A subprocess?

Comment: Yes, like a subprocess.

Comment: If you don't have heavy computation, threads are good enough.